# trying to send array through GET variable, when printed, var equals string of 'Array'

Tags: php, arrays, url, get

Whenever i build a URL i.e.

```
cart.php?action=add&p[]=29&qty[]=3&p[]=5&qty[]=13
```

and try to grab the p variable and the qty variable, the = 'Array'

var_dump =

```
array(3) { ["action"]=>  string(3) "add" ["p"]=>  string(5) "Array" ["qty"]=>  string(5) "Array" }
```

I create half the URL with PHP, and the other half is concatenated with Javascript.

Comment: Can you give us the `print_r` of your `$_GET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P and QTY are Arrays because you created them using the `variable[]` syntax. And when you try to turn an array into a string, PHP just use's 'Array'. Echoing something turns it into a string, and then prints it to the string.

The `[]` tells PHP to make a new key in the array numerically, and assign the value to it.

If you want to get acess of the values of `p`, go like this

```
foreach($_GET['p'] as $value)
{
     // $value is one of the values of the array, and it goes through all of them
}
```

The foreach iterates through all of the values of the array, where `$value` is the value of the current element you are working on.

If you want to access the first value assigned to `p`, use

```
echo $_GET['p'][0];
```

Comment: i understand why they're arrays, it's just every way i've tried to get the values from those arrays has been fruitless. so i my question is more, how to i return the values from those arrays.

Comment: I provided methodology for accessing element in the array, could you be more specific?

Comment: Oh wait, I guess I didn't read your question clearly enough. Give me a second.

Comment: well whats happening right now is if i do the foreach it just spells Array. for instance
$_GET['p'][0] = 'A'
$_GET['p'][1] = 'r'
$_GET['p'][2] = 'r'
$_GET['p'][3] = 'a'
$_GET['p'][4] = 'y'

Comment: Ok, so for some reason it is the word array instead of being an actual array. Do you do anything weird to `$_GET`?

Comment: nope, i create the url 'cart.php?action=add&p=29' and then use javascript to add just a couple more variables onto the end of the url. then in javascript window.location = url. ?

Comment: I have no idea. That just seems weird.

Comment: You might want to have it submit `POST` data instead of creating a GET url. POST Data is more apt to arrays of data than GET.

Comment: exactly. i mean as long as it remains a string the whole time and everything is correct in the string it should work? but no matter what i try, it prints 'Array' as the variable

Comment: the only problem with that is that my boss built this whole shopping cart based on GET. don't have the time frame to switch everything up

Comment: You might want to see if using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php will break it apart. You can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and parse it.